# VisualState Setter with CustomControl not working

Tags: win-universal-app, windows-10, visualstatemanager, imagesource

I hava a UserControl that Contains a Button and a Image Control and a Property like this:

```
 public sealed partial class ImageButton : UserControl
        {
            public ImageSource Source { get { return Image.Source; } set { Image.Source = value; } }
        }
```

Setting the ImageSource in XAML works fine like this:

```
<views:ImageButton x:Name="MyButton" Source="../Assets/image.jpg"/>
```

But when I try to set it in VisualStateManager it breaks the complete State:

```
<Setter Target="MyButton.Source" Value="../Assets/image.jpg"/>
```

As usual Windows spits out no (helpful) error message, so I have no idea what is wrong here. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, found it out myself: You need to register the Source Property as DependencyProperty

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Source",
            typeof (ImageSource), typeof (ImageButton), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty, OnPropertyChanged));

private static void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                ((ImageButton) d).Source = (ImageSource) e.NewValue;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use dependency property. Below is one sample solution for elaboration:

User control

```
<UserControl
x:Class="TestApps.ImageButton"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:TestApps"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300"
d:DesignWidth="400" x:Name="MyControl">

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Image Source="{Binding ElementName=MyControl, Path=Source, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    <Button Content="{Binding ElementName=MyControl, Path=ButtonContent, Mode=OneWay}" 
            Grid.Row="1" Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

User control code behind

```
public sealed partial class ImageButton : UserControl
{
    public ImageButton()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string Source
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(SourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SourceProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Source.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Source", typeof(string), typeof(ImageButton), new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));

    public string ButtonContent
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(ButtonContentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ButtonContentProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Source.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonContentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ButtonContent", typeof(string), typeof(ImageButton), new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));
}
```

Parent XAML

```
<StackPanel Margin="100,10,10,10">
        <local:ImageButton Source="../Assets/SplashScreen.scale-200.png" ButtonContent="Test Button!"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

Output
[image]